# ICMP distinguish error messages

Tags: protocol-theory, icmp

Can a Internet Control Message Protocol when an error is sent can it tell which datagram that made the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many cases, an ICMP error message contains the header of the packet that caused the error.

Example: The ICMP Type3 Code 3 "Port Unreachable" response from a "server" (172.19.41.35) to an unsolicited UDP packet generated with iperf2 from a "client" (172.19.41.135) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6os6n.png)

The blue frame shows the packet that caused the error; the error in this case was that the responding system did not have an open socket on port udp/5001 (because iperf2 was not running on the responding system).

[image: Wireshark packet analysis/dissection of an ICMP type code 3 "port unreachable" message]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6os6n.png) Please note that neither ICMP, UDP nor TCP have a concept of *client* or *server* - these are application layer concepts. If at all, there is the notion of an *initiator* and *responder*.

Answer (score 3):

An ICMP error message will contain the IP header and first 64 bits (eight octets) of the original data. See *[RFC 792, Internet Message Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792)*:

> Internet Header + 64 bits of Data Datagram
>
> The internet header plus the first 64 bits of the original datagram's
> data. This data is used by the host to match the message to the
> appropriate process. If a higher level protocol uses port numbers,
> they are assumed to be in the first 64 data bits of the original
> datagram's data.